# How to convert password to MD5

Tags: sql, postgresql, passwords

I've got a column `user_password` where passwords are stored with `bytea` datatype.

I want to select all columns in this table, and password to be converted in the results into MD5.

Currently examplary password is like this `4\323\227\120\0817Z\303\101`

I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

Using update query

```
 update table_name set user_password = MD5(user_password)
```

Comment: But I don't want to modify the table itself, just want to display the results converted

Answer (score 0):

Jeeez. It was so easy I didn't even realized. just select md5(login_password) worked.